# How do you determine the running time complexity for these problems?

Tags: data-structures, big-o

I need to determine the running time for each program.

```
constTimeFunction(n): T(n) = O(1)

linTimeFunction(n): T(n) = O(n)

quadTimeFunction(n): T(n) = O(n^2)

cubeTimeFunction(n): T(n) = O(n^3)
```

I've provided my answers. Am I wrong?

**Program 1:**

```
for (i=0; i<4*n; ++i) { 

   linTimeFunction( n );

   quadTimeFunction( n );

   constTimeFunction( n );

}
```

The running time is O(n^3).

**Program 2:**

```
for (i=0; i<3; ++i) {

     for (j=0; j<n; ++j) {

       linTimeFunction( n );

       linTimeFunction( n );

       linTimeFunction( n );
    }

}
```

The running time is O(n^2).

**Program 3:**

```
for (i=0;i<9*n;++i) {

   cubeTimeFunction( n );

     for (j=0;j<5;++j) {

       quadTimeFunction( n ); 

     } 

   linTimeFunction( n ); 

}
```

The running time is O(n^5).

Comment: The same way you do for any programming language. What are you really asking?

Comment: Look at the definitions given: `quadTimeFunction` is O(n^2), *not* O(n^4) - it stands for [*Quadratic Time*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_time), and *not* "n raised to the 4". (As such, not all the answers are correct, or maybe the answer to #1 is wrong for other reasons :)

Comment: (The other reason why #1 might have been answered incorrectly is forgetting that `C*O(n) = O(C*n)`, and C can be "forgotten". Except in real life when time *really* matters ;-)

Answer (score 0):

(1) would be O(n^3), assuming quad is quadratic.  The others are correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is one (formal) manner, among many others, of how you can deduce the order of growth of iterative algorithms:

[image]